# i want to make background service in android app , which should keep running even when app is closed

Tags: android, background-service

i want to make background service in android app, which should keep running always even when app in closed, killed or background state, i currently have background service which works well when app is minimized but when i close app, and killed app it does not work. the socket is closed if app kills 
even i used android isolated Process true.....
i want to make socket available in any condition

```
public class MyTestService extends IntentService {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private Socket tempClientSocket;
Thread serverThread = null;
public static final int SERVER_PORT = 3001;

public MyTestService() {
    // Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
    super("test-service");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate(); // if you override onCreate(), make sure to call super().
    // If a Context object is needed, call getApplicationContext() here.
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Socket socket;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (null != serverSocket) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                try {
                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    String mess = input.readLine();
                    BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bf,true);
                    out.println("message recieve");
                    input.close();
                    bf.close();
                    serverSocket.close();

                    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "asdsadasd")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                            .setContentTitle("Title")
                            .setContentText(mess)
                            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                            .setAutoCancel(true);

                    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
                    notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly what you're wanting to do I would look at [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).

```
fun workRequest() {

    val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .setRequiresCharging(true)
        .setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)
        .build()

    val worker: WorkRequest =
        PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<DetailsWorker>(6, TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .setInputData(workRequestData)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(worker)
}
```

Comment: how and where to use it sir because i have created a service and used socket based listening code there in separate thread.

Comment: i actually want to run a service in background which receive data from socket even app kills..

Comment: i have updated my question please check it and tell me in this situation how i get my goal i have provided code which i have used

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JobScheduler` in the Android framework API for scheduling tasks or work in background. You can also specify network type or the the period you want to run the job or few other parameters.
Create a class that extends the `JobService` class and override the onStartJob and onStopJob method.

```
public class myJob extends JobService {
      public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
      }
       public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
      }
 }
```

Within the `OnStartJob` write the code you want to run in background.
Add this to the `JobInfo` which is used to configure how the jobservice should run.

```
JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(jobID, new ComponentName(context, Myjob.service));
```

On  JobInfo.Builder` you can include the scheduling criteria. Eg:

```
    builder.setPeriodic(10000);
    builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
```

Create an instance of `Jobscheduler` and pass the `JobInfo` data from above. This will call the `JobService` class based on the scheduling parameter you have specified.

```
JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

Here's more info on jobscheduler: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling

Comment: sir i have updated my question please review it and tell me in this condition how i achieve my goal ...

Comment: Whats your api version..? is it going to be below API 26?